# Microsoft identity platform Asp.Net c# and Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-4.5, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an application developed in Asp.Net 4.5. Authentication and authorization are done through Asp.Net Identities. The application was developed in Visual Studio 2013.

I now want to move to Microsoft identity platform.

Which versions of Asp.Net and Visual Studios should be compatible for transfering my application to Microsoft identity platform?

I've seen examples that require Visual Studio 2017 or 2019. Is that necessary or can earlier versions be compatible? Even if earlier versions can be compatible will it be easier and better to work with the latest version?

Comment: Your question does not really make sense. VS is an IDE. It is not tied directly to any version of asp.net or MS Identity. If you are looking for what version of VS can you use try the latest version (2019 as of writing this). You can run different versions of VS side by side on the same PC.

Comment: @Igor True VS is an IDE but their different versions were built to work with certain laguages and their versions and also built to work "naturaly" and easily with certain platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically shouldn't be any issue with VS2013. You might have to install a few extra SDK's that come packaged into the later VS versions (eg. the azure SDK) but even then, they're still going to be available.

The only pain points you might hit are going to be around finding tutorials that you can follow along with, as most of the ones I can see with a quick google are asking for .net 4.7+ and vs2017+. Still, there are libraries for Microsoft identity platform that support .net 4.5, so there will be a way.

Comment: Thank you Callum your answer is very helpful!